# Is WindowsAzure.targets ValidateServiceFiles an essential build step?

Tags: azure, msbuild

We have a problem with our azure build such that we can only get it to work if we use absolute paths in the WebRole/Contents/Content/SourceDirectory sections of our csdef file. Although it does support relative paths (including '..') and environment variables (! Yes as in SET) the problem is we cant get any non-absolute path to successfully build because it appears the .csdef file is "validated" twice: once where it sits in the project directory before packaging, and once again after it had been moved to the /bin folder. Obviously there is no one relative path that will be able to resolve to the same content directories if we start in two separate places! What you can do is get the paths right for ONE of the two build steps phases... but then it will fail on the other. The offending target is PreValidateServiceModel which calls the ValidateServiceFiles task.

In order to make my project build using relative paths i need to disable the PreValidateServiceModel target. The packaging *appears* to work although I'm worried some vital process is being missed by skipping the targets (aside from the obvious... the service files are not validated!). That said the .csdef file is still "validated" in the sense it has to be parsed to create the package.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Checking the [documentation on the Source directory element of the WebRole schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg557553.aspx#SourceDirectory), I saw that environment variable expension in the directory path is supported. This led me to the following solution.

In a pre-build event of the project containing the csdef file, I copy my files from the UpdaterFiles directory to a directory under the Temp directory:

```
IF NOT EXIST %TEMP%\UpdaterFiles MKDIR %TEMP%\UpdaterFiles
XCOPY $(ProjectDir)..\UpdaterFiles\*.* %TEMP%\UpdaterFiles\ /Y
```

Then my source directory just becomes:

```
<SourceDirectory path="%TEMP%\UpdaterFiles" />
```

The above works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different solution, which avoids copying to temp.

As already mentioned, the problem is that the relative path does not work from two different places:

```
1. ProjectFolder\ServiceDefinition.csdef
2. ProjectFolder\bin\Debug\ServiceDefinition.csdef
```

So I moved the source location of ServiceDefinition.csdef down two folder levels, so that the same relative path will work in both cases:

```
1. ProjectFolder\Service\Definition\ServiceDefinition.csdef
2. ProjectFolder\bin\Debug\ServiceDefinition.csdef
```

To do this, I edited the project file (right click, 'Edit Project File') and changed:

```
<ServiceDefinition Include="ServiceDefinition.csdef" />
```

into:

```
<ServiceDefinition Include="Service\Definition\ServiceDefinition.csdef" />
```

I created those two sub-folders in Windows Explorer and moved the file to its new location. Then I reloaded the project.

I noticed that Visual Studio automatically added these two lines for me:

```
<Folder Include="Service\" />
<Folder Include="Service\Definition\" />
```

In my ServiceDefinition.csdef file, I refer to the source directory by going up three folders to the solution folder, and then navigating from there:

```
<SourceDirectory path="..\..\..\MySourceProject\MySourceFolder" />
```